# Breadth-first inter-transaction semantics

Tags: michelson

In the « inter-transaction semantics » section of the [Michelson specification](https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/michelson.html) it appears that when a contract emits internal operations (which in turn can emit their own) the overall evaluation sequence is analogous to a « breadth-first » search of a graph.

I am curious as to what are the pros/cons of this approach compared to eg a « depth-first » approach ?

One aspect i see of breadth-first is that it allows for easier sequencing of the operations in a queue but depth-first somehow allows for ensuring the context is « consistent » at the time op1b is evaluated since all of the effects of op1a would have already been factored in the context.

Comment: That's how they do communication between vats in erights. There's a smart explanation for it but I don't recall it on top of my head.

Comment: http://erights.org/elib/concurrency/queuing.html